# Finding closed form solution for $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \sqrt{1-\alpha^n}-1 \right)$, where $\alpha=1-1/\pi $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Could you please help me to find the closed form solution (if exists?) for the following sum:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \sqrt{1-\alpha^n}-1 \right)
$$
where
$$
 \alpha = 1 - 1/\pi 
$$

Wolfram Alpha gives the value is approximately $-1.22875$, but I cannot solve that analytically.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I strongly suspect you cannot get a closed form for this. Also you should bracket: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\sqrt{1-a^n}-1)$$

Comment: In fact, I interpreted it as the sum minus $1$

Comment: @FShrike do you think it is a good idea to just fix the question for them? Or would you rather they fix it themselves? I dont have the reputation to change the question myself.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to add those parentheses, and also adjusted the lower bound to $n=1$ (otherwise the approximate value would be $-2.22875$). Please check that this is what you meant.

Comment: What do you mean with "prove" ? The given numerical value is (at least I assume it) only an approximation. A proof would work only if we would have the exact value of the sum (which does not seem to be possible)

Comment: My apologies for confusion. Yes, it should be in the brackets. Thank you for editing the request.

Answer (score 2):

Use the expansion of
$$\sqrt{1-t}-1=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k} t^k$$ Make $t=\alpha^n$ and switch the summations
$$S_p=\sum _{k=1}^p (-1)^{k}\,\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}\,\frac{  \alpha ^k}{1-\alpha^k}\qquad \text{with} \qquad \alpha=1-\frac 1 \pi$$

Now, **compute** and notice that $S_{10}$ is already $-1.22844$

**Edit**

Because of a question in comments, compare the two different summations
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 p & \text{original summation}  & \text{proposed summation} \\
 1 & -0.43581041645224 & -1.07079632679490 \\
 2 & -0.70416939195646 & -1.17931085986638 \\
 3 & -0.87759958724692 & -1.20828976227261 \\
 4 & -0.99213214100214 & -1.21904853712298 \\
 5 & -1.06866541653547 & -1.22376863007515 \\
 6 & -1.12016716261171 & -1.22605616767305 \\
 7 & -1.15497719534273 & -1.22723939273418 \\
 8 & -1.17857219754488 & -1.22787978095566 \\
 9 & -1.19459529036594 & -1.22823799223784 \\
 10 & -1.20548991233807 & -1.22844340615641 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Hi Claude. I was expecting a original approach from you. Cheers !

Comment: Without an explicit error estimate this tells us *nothing* about the value of the infinite series.

Comment: What's difference between the initial sum and yours? Yours sum converges more quickly?

Comment: @NN2. Good question ! I shall edit and put some numbers.

Answer (score 1):

What make you think that there exist a closed form made of a finite number of standard constants and/or functions ?

A more accurate numerical value is :
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \sqrt{1-\left(1-\frac{1}{\pi}\right)^n}-1 \right)=-2.228745916035319...$$
The  Simon Plouffe's Inverse Symbolic Calculator of the Canadian Centre for Experimental and Constructive Mathematics (Burnaby, Canada) gives a far approximate :
$$-\text{Hypergeometric}\,_2F_3\big((\frac29,\frac37);(\frac45,\frac14,\frac12);1\big)=-2.228746060570045...$$
My own "toy" Inverse Symbolic Calculator (https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14161596/Mathematiques-experimentales ) gives this surprising formula which is obviously not correct on analytic viewpoint :
$$-\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{-\sin(5)}\right)^{1/3}\exp\left(\frac{-\gamma}{\sin(2)} \right)=-2.228745916103497...$$
$\gamma$ is the  Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Of course this isn't an answer as expected but a comment.

Comment: Hi Jean ! Nice to see you.

Comment: What is the numerical value that you showed? It doesn't seem to be the value of the post owner's sum. And what is the Inverse Symbolic Calculator that you mentioned? Is it a "calculator"?

Comment: @NN2 Note that in this answer the sum starts at $n=0$ adding an extra $-1$ to the final value.

Comment: @Gary I see now. Thank you

Comment: How did you (or your "Inverse Symbolic Calculator") find the formula
$$-\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{-\sin(5)}\right)^{1/3}\exp\left(\frac{-\gamma}{\sin(2)} \right)$$

Comment: @NN2. Probably the principle of my ISC is similar to the principle of the Simon Pfouffe's ISC and others. See : Wikipedia, Inverse Symbolic Calculator.

Comment: Several references in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322628/how-does-inverse-symbolic-calculator-work.

Comment: I don't know if there is a closed form solution. Basically, I have been requested to find a closed form solution if it exists...I tried to use Riemann summation tricks, but couldn't get an answer.